# Can it be created as dynamic variables instead of hardcoding them by if statements in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

The Javascript code below shows some examples of how I'd like `j` and `k` to look like for something further to do in my own codes, in a bunch of hardcoded `if` statements inside the function `fetch()`. However, I don't want to use the `if` statements as I have to write 16 of them for all the possible combinations of whether each variable (`b`, `c`, `d`, or `e`) would be in variable `j` or `k`. I'd like to have another alternative that is more efficient. Basically I'd like it to do a couple of things:

1. Check all the `xOct` if they are greater than 3 or not.
2. If the `xOct` is greater than 3, put the related characters (variables `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`) and the corresponding `xOct` into variable `j`. If the `xOct` is less than 3, put the other related characters (variables `f`, `g`, `h`, `i`) and the corresponding `xOct` into variable `k`.
3. If there are more than 1 "character + `xOct`" put in the same variable (`j` or `k`), add a space after the `xOct` before adding another "character + `xOct`", as well as a `(` at the beginning of either `j` or `k`, and a `)` at the end of either one of them.
4. At the end of either `j` or `k`, add the text `/w`.
5. If there is nothing put in either `j` or `k`, then leave it blank as `""`.

I'd like to ask if there are other ways to create such dynamic variables for both `j` and `k`, possibly some functions or some loops maybe, instead of listing all the possibilities and hardcoding them in a bunch of if statements like in below?

```js
const pc = ["C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B"];
const text1 = document.getElementById("text1");
const text2 = document.getElementById("text2");

let b = "";
let c = "";
let d = "";
let e = "";

let f = "";
let g = "";
let h = "";
let i = "";

let j = "";
let k = "";

window.onload = fetch();

function fetch() {
  var bPc = Math.floor(Math.random() * pc.length);
  var cPc = Math.floor(Math.random() * pc.length);
  var dPc = Math.floor(Math.random() * pc.length);
  var ePc = Math.floor(Math.random() * pc.length);
  var fPc = Math.floor(Math.random() * pc.length);
  var gPc = Math.floor(Math.random() * pc.length);
  var hPc = Math.floor(Math.random() * pc.length);
  var iPc = Math.floor(Math.random() * pc.length);

  var bOct = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  var cOct = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  var dOct = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  var eOct = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);

  b += pc[bPc];
  c += pc[cPc];
  d += pc[dPc];
  e += pc[ePc];
  f += pc[fPc];
  g += pc[gPc];
  h += pc[hPc];
  i += pc[iPc];

  if (bOct > 3 && cOct > 3 && dOct > 3 && eOct > 3) {
    j += "(" + b + bOct + " " + c + cOct + " " + d + dOct + " " + e + eOct + ")/w";
    k += "";
  } else if (bOct <= 3 && cOct <= 3 && dOct <= 3 && eOct <= 3) {
    j += "";
    k += "(" + f + bOct + " " + g + cOct + " " + h + dOct + " " + i + eOct + ")/w";
  } else if (bOct > 3 && cOct <= 3 && dOct <= 3 && eOct <= 3) {
    j += b + bOct + "/w";
    k += "(" + g + cOct + " " + h + dOct + " " + i + eOct + ")/w";
  } //more and more "else if" combinations omitted

    text1.innerHTML = j;
    text2.innerHTML = k;
}
```

```html
<p id="text1"></p>
<p id="text2"></p>
```

Comment: I assume this is something to do with musical notation but it is very difficult to read/follow as the names are a little confuzzling and thus the true nature of the problem is something of a puzzle itself

Comment: @professorabronsius I disagree - if you read the 5 step requirement statement it is perfectly clear.

Comment: The meaning is not clear of "all the possibilities" and "more and more 'else if' combinations omitted", but it sounds to me like this is a [combinatorics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics) problem (SO tag: [tag:combinatorics]). We can't help without a full understanding of the rules governing the desired variations of your imagined set of conditions… you'd need to describe that in a way such that any person reading the question (with the required domain knowledge) would be able to reproduce the full list of conditions manually.

Comment: @jsejcksn Sorry for the confusion. There should be 16 combinations (2 ^ 4), which means 16 if statements if it's been done by my way, which I think is too inefficient and clumsy.

Comment: @Nikkorian - ah, you overlook the fact that I am a simpleton

Comment: @professorabronsius - a sweet response - finally we encounter some humility on this site. We are all here to learn. You and I are fellow travellers.

Comment: To shorten, I'd need a little more background. There does seem to be some pattern here. Variables named bPc ... iPC implies some relationship to the underlying data.

Comment: Your asking us to blindly optimize your code as a compiler would do. I can shorten the code, but it would be harder to understand.

You have provided a solution to a problem. We need a description to of the problem.

Comment: @historystamp The problem is that I want an alternative of my if statements in my code, and it will carry out actions according to my 5 points of statement, which is perfectly solved by Nikkorian's answer, unless there is a more efficient solution that that, which would be always welcomed.

Comment: Why in the world has this been closed?  I have another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your IF statement with the following

```
  j = (bOct > 3 )? j + b + bOct + " " : j;
  j = (cOct > 3 )? j + c + cOct + " " : j;
  j = (dOct > 3 )? j + d + dOct + " " : j;
  j = (eOct > 3 )? j + e + eOct + " " : j;
  k = (bOct  <=  3 )? k + f + bOct + " " : k;
  k = (cOct  <=  3 )? k + g + cOct + " " : k;
  k = (dOct  <=  3 )? k + h + dOct + " " : k;
  k = (eOct  <=  3 )? k + i + eOct + " " : k;
  j = j.trim().indexOf(" ") !== -1 ? "("+j+")": j;
  k = k.trim().indexOf(" ") !== -1 ? "("+k+")": k;
  j = j.trim().length !== 0 ? j+"/w": j;
  k = k.trim().length !== 0 ? k+"/w": k; 
  j=j.replace(" )",")").replace(" /","/");
  k=k.replace(" )",")").replace(" /","/");
```

EDIT
A cleaner version of this code is as follows:

```
  j = (bOct > 3 )? j + b + bOct + " " : j;
  j = (cOct > 3 )? j + c + cOct + " " : j;
  j = (dOct > 3 )? j + d + dOct + " " : j;
  j = (eOct > 3 )? j + e + eOct + " " : j;
  k = (bOct  <=  3 )? k + f + bOct + " " : k;
  k = (cOct  <=  3 )? k + g + cOct + " " : k;
  k = (dOct  <=  3 )? k + h + dOct + " " : k;
  k = (eOct  <=  3 )? k + i + eOct + " " : k;
  j = j.trim();
  k = k.trim();
  j = j.indexOf(" ") !== -1 ? "("+j+")": j;
  k = k.indexOf(" ") !== -1 ? "("+k+")": k;
  j = j.length !== 0 ? j+"/w": j;
  k = k.length !== 0 ? k+"/w": k;
```

Comment: seems very repetitive to me instead of using a loop.

Comment: @tacoshy My code examines each of 8 xOct variables once each. You cannot achieve the result without this, nor any more efficiently. It is also executed only once in the OP's example in the onLoad event, so there is no benefit in using functions.  I considered using functions but in the context of the OP's question using functions would have in fact been slower.

Comment: I have a potential solution using an associative array.  never say never

Comment: Check out an associative array pseudocode proposal.  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DHqRx3WsZ-tX9IxyNesrSYJnK65TkZ3w/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=114266596581803752800&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: @historystamp You may write your answer here again now

Comment: @historystamp What your solution does is provide an alternative way of storing the generated random values. But they all still have to be generated, so there's no timesaving offered. What you have not covered is the examination of those values and building of the j and k strings, which is what the OP asked about. Again, each one has to be tested against the value 3, and a decision made as to how to modify j and k. Could you show us how you would do that?